# Multiple rows in a single TextView

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I have an application that has a Database of vehicles with multiple fields.
I then have a ListView in which I want to display some of the fields.
Currently I have this:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter vehicleAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.vehiclerow, vehicleCursor, new String[] {"registration"}, new int[] { R.id.vehicleRow});
```

And I want to put multiple values on the vehicleRow TextView for instance:

```
Toyota - Corolla
```

in which Toyota and Corolla come from separate fields of the database.

I've tried this:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter vehicleAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.vehiclerow, vehicleCursor, new String[] {"make", "model"}, new int[] { R.id.vehicleRow});
```

but it doesn't work.

What could be the problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only map one data field to one view with the standard adapters.

You either need to create a custom adapter to let you put two data fields.into one widget (not always trivial) or create a new rowlayout with the necessary textviews and use that with a standard adapter.

I'd go for the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Create another TextView and entered its Id in the cursorAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

try in this way :

```
String[] from = new String[]{DbManager.Title, DbManager.Date}; 
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.list_name_main,R.id.list_date_main};{                   
        Adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item_by_list, c1, from, to);       
        //Adapter.setViewBinder(new ScoreHistoryBinder());
        list_item.setAdapter(Adapter);
        list_item.setOnItemClickListener(listOnItemClickListener);}
```

Comment: { R.id.list_name_main,R.id.list_date_main}; are textviews in row.xml